# Why are some object members out of scope in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I'm coming to Objective-C from a Java background. I'm having trouble understanding why the following code generates an exception.

```
    
@interface Stopwatch : NSObject {
    NSDate *start;
    int    mode;
}
@property(nonatomic,assign) NSDate *start;
@property(nonatomic,assign) int mode;
@end

@implementation Stopwatch
@synthesize start, mode;
-(id) init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        start = [NSDate date];
        mode = -1;
    }
    return self;
}
@end


@interface StopwatchController : NSObject {
    Stopwatch *stopwatch;
}
@property (nonatomic,assign) Stopwatch *stopwatch;

- (void) useStopwatch:(Stopwatch*)aStopwatch;
- (void) updateStopwatch;
@end

@implementation StopwatchController
@synthesize stopwatch;

- (void) useStopwatch:(Stopwatch*)aStopwatch{
    stopwatch = aStopwatch;
}

- (void) updateStopwatch{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormat setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [dateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    NSString *string = [dateFormat stringFromDate:stopwatch.start];
    NSLog(@"%@",string);
}
@end
```

So when the following code is run I see that the stopwatch.start is out of scope, but not the stopwatch?

```
Stopwatch *sw = [[Stopwatch alloc]init];
StopwatchControlelr *swc = [[StopwatchController alloc]init];
[swc useStopwatch:sw];
[swc updateStopwatch];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your init

```
start = [NSDate date];
```

Does not use the start property -- it uses the start instance variable.  This means that a retain was never called.  [NSDate date] returns an object that will autorelease.

My advice is to use

```
self.start = [NSDate date];
```

This uses the property.  In your case, I would also declare this property `retain`, not `assign`.  If you keep it `assign`, you need to call retain.  So with `assign`, also do this

```
[self.start retain];
```

One way to make sure you do it right is to declare fields like this

```
NSDate * _start;
```

Properties like this

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSDate * start;
```

and then sythesize like this

```
@synthesize start = _start.
```

Then you know when you are using the instance variable (which bypasses any set calls, automatic retains, etc) or the property.

If you did that, then this would not compile

```
   start = [NSDate date];
```

You'd either need to change to this

```
   self.start = [NSDate date]; // use property
```

or this

```
   _start = [NSDate date]; // use instance variable
```

Answer (score 1):

`[NSDate date]` gives you an autoreleased instance which will be deallocated when the associated autorelease pool is drained. You have to retain it to take ownership, see the documentation on [Cocoa Memory Management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-SW1).