# iOS keepAlive callback instance variables

Tags: objective-c, background, callback

When my handler is called by the system, I seem to loose some pointers to instance variables.

In my .m implementation I have

```
@implementation BackgroundWorker

MyApplication* myApp;
NSDate* lastUpdate;
```

and in my handler that variable is no longer valid:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setKeepAliveTimeout:600 handler:^{

  // myApp is valid however

  // Check that enough time has passed
  NSDate* now = [NSDate date];

  if (lastUpdate == nil ||         // <--- lastUpdate not a valid object
    [now timeIntervalSinceDate:lastUpdate] >= TIME_RESOLUTION_SEC) {

    // do stuff

    lastUpdate = now;
  }

}];
```

I initialise **lastUpdate** correctly at class method and it is valid the first time the app runs, but if it goes to background and the handler is called the variable is no longer valid.

Any way of telling the OS not to destroy/clear an instance variable between background callbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution on another thread:

[Why are some object members out of scope in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354559/why-are-some-object-members-out-of-scope-in-objective-c)

It has to do with properties vs supporting variables etc.

I had to assign NSDate to a property instead of the supporting variable...

Answer (score 1):

Store the value in the app delegate, but I would most likely store it in the NSUserdefaults and pull the value every time you need it. This will also keep the value if the user kills the app.

Comment: Thank you that's what Im doing now, but I am wondering if there is way to avoid the IO in and from NSUserdefaults. Would it be possible to "detect" when the instances are flushed?

Comment: Did you try making the variable accessible through a property?

Comment: Are you saying you call the handler (block) while it's in the background? Or are you saying it comes back from the background and calls the handler (block) and it doesn't execute correctly.

Comment: Hi Benny, the handler block is called by OS in background and although I have access to some instances of local variables, others are now invalid (address range wrong). I could handle this if I knew that iOS killed or flushed my app, but the docs say it does it without notice and then I wonder how come some pointers are valid where the NSDate variable pointers are invalid.

Comment: PS: Yes I did try providing properties for those NSDate variables and still the same occurred (supporting internal variable was messed again)

Comment: This most likely reason has something to do with your lastUpdate variable getting statically copied into the block which means it has a specific spot in memory. My guess is at some point that specific spot is getting erased. I think I would go back with my original suggestion and make the variable in your app delegate. Then set and get it from there.

Comment: I will try and let you know in couple of days. Thank you!